# How to check in javascript if url address start with defined string?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check if a url address starts with for example: http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use normal string searching:

```
// if the url begins with this string
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/') == 0) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Comment: I don't get the `indexOf()` part. Can't you do `if (window.location.href == 'http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/')`?

Comment: That checks if the whole URL exactly matches, not just the beginning.

Comment: Cool, got it! Was overreading the term **start** in the question anyway. ;)

Comment: should be === -1, not == 0

Comment: @CătălinRădoi That tests if it doesn't contain the string.

Comment: @Barmar ups, you are right, my bad

Answer (score 3):

```
if (url.startsWith("http://google.com/")) {
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions. You can just do it like this

```
str="http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/blah"
function search(string){
    return (string.indexOf(str)==0)
}
```