# javascript location href with asterix

Tags: javascript, location, href

i was wondering if its possible to run an event based on url with asterix.
So for example lets say i want to run an event if i'm on https://mypage.com but i also want to run the event on https://mypage.com/?page=2 and page 3 and page 4 etc is there any way to do this in javascript. I thought something like this should work

```
if(window.location.href == "https://mypage.com/*") {
    alert("Yes");
} else{
    alert("No");
}
```

But it returns No

Comment: Use RegExp or in this case `startsWith`.

Comment: [Wildcard string comparison in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246601/wildcard-string-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in javascript if url address start with defined string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518395/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-url-address-start-with-defined-string)